# Counting Invokations in Preprocessor Macros

Tags: c

I need a macro which when substituted each time keep track of the number of such substitution,
The purpose of this is to have a diffrent macro expansion when the macro expansion reaches multiple of a certan integer. no runtime overhead is acceptable.(I cannot use inline functions, if condition checks etc.)

I tried `__COUNTER__` as follows:

```
 #define ABC() (__COUNTER__ > 5)? printf("\n hello"): printf("\n ok").
```

but `__COUNTER__` doesn't work when this macro is in a loop.

The printf above used only as an example.

please note that the macro is expanded in time critical context and function overhead is not acceptable as well as the conditional branching in assembly, the above ternary operator is used because the assembly generated contains a conditional instruction rather than conditional branching.

any other methods , suggestions?

Comment: A loop is a runtime construct, so you can't count invocations at compile time with a macro.

Comment: Doing *anything* that can't be solved by the preprocessor or the compiler during compile-time, will incur runtime overhead. In this case tertiary condition expression and the calling of `printf`.

Comment: Also, a macro isn't really *invoked*, the preprocessor simply does a search-replace, which is why it will not work in a loop as the macro is only "invoked" once (when the preprocessor does the macro substitution).

Comment: @joachim  thanks for pointing out ,edited to modify "invocation"

Comment: Do you know what macros are and what they do?

Comment: @Nit I heard SO is a friendly place , i am here to know whether any such macro tricks exist for the situation i am facing.

Comment: What you are asking is not possible without runtime overhead. Obviously your macro will do something, which will anyway have some time requirements. So the question is; how much overhead is too much? What you are trying to do? Are you trying to avoid branching?

Comment: @user694733 - i have to avoid any branching which creates a bubble in the pipeline. branch prediction on my CPU is negative displacement predicted as taken.

Answer (score -1):

If the count requirement is low you could avoid branches with array and function pointers.

```
typedef void(*Func)(void);
typedef struct {
    Func run;
    int next;
} Element;

void first(void) {
    printf("\n hello");
}
void second(void) {
    printf("\n ok");
}

Element array[] = {
    { first, 1 },
    { first, 2 },
    { first, 3 },
    { first, 4 },
    { second, 4 }
};
int i = 0;

#define ABC() \
    do { \
        array[i].run(); \
        i = array[i].next; \
    } while(0)
```

Comment: @user694733- appreciate the effort.it wont work for me. I am doing a write on a bus bridge which can buffer writes and on a certain number of writes i need to flush the buffer.